# PGFplots - Problem with "colorbar as legend" option

Tags: pgfplots, color, legend

I have a problem when I use the option `colorbar as legend` : the displayed `tick labels` are incorrect. After looking in the PGFplots manual, I noticed that the example given also had this problem.

Is it possible to remedy this?

Here is a simple example using the `colormap` given in the manual :

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{
    compat=newest,
    colormap={colorbarAsLegend}{
        of colormap={
            viridis,
            target pos={0,200,300,350,375,400,700,800,850,1000},
            sample for=const,
        }
    },
}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotscolorbardrawstandalone[
    colormap name=colorbarAsLegend,
    colormap access=const,
]
\pgfplotscolorbardrawstandalone[
    colorbar as legend,
    colormap name=colorbarAsLegend,
    colormap access=const,
]
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[colorbar as legend,
        colormap name=colorbarAsLegend,
        colormap access=const,
        ]
        \addplot [mesh, very thick] {x};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Consider reporting this on [`pgfplots`' issue tracker](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgfplots/issues).

Comment: Which version of pgfplots do you use? I have 1.16 running on Tex Live 2019 and there your code produces the correct result, i.e., different from your screenshot.

Comment: @Marijin I’m sorry for the late answer. I had a computer problem and I was only able to reinstall MikTeX last week after 3 months. I think MikTeX’s built-in package manager has automatically downloaded the latest version available on CTAN, i. e. version 1. 17 and I still have the same problem with that version.